# Quando usar o cin.ignore() em C++?

Tags: c++

Qual o momento exato para utilizar o `cin.ignore()` em um software escrito em C++? Por que muita das vezes, quando estou fazendo um software grande, as leituras ficam bugando, as vezes se eu colocar `cin.ignore()` desbuga, as vezes buga mais.

Então, qual  o jeito certo de se utilizar o `cin.ignore()` ?

Comment: Uma [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475384/when-and-why-do-i-need-to-use-cin-ignore-in-c) similar

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Como o próprio nome já sugere, o `cin.ignore()` é usado quando se quer ignorar um ou mais caracteres do *buffer* de entrada.

> Qual o momento exato para utilizar o cin.ignore() em um software escrito em C++?

O `cin.ignore()` trata como delimitador os caracteres: `\t` e `\n`, então você vai usar quando receber uma entrada e quiser ignorar esses caracteres que permaneceram no *buffer* de entrada.

> Então, qual o jeito certo de se utilizar o cin.ignore() ?

De forma bem resumida, você usa em casos que queira ignorar caracteres não lidos no *buffer* de entrada, como já citei.

**Ex:**

1. Você quer receber uma `string` do usuário e armazenar em um `char`:

   `char teste[20];`
2. Vai ler a entrada usando o `cin`:

   `cin >> teste;`
3. Supondo que o usuário digitou `teste` e apertou ENTER. O `teste` vai ser recebido, e o `\n`vai permanecer no *buffer* de entrada.
4. Usando o `cin.ignore()` o caracter `\n`que permanecer no *buffer* de entrada vai ser ignorado.

Tentei ser o mais breve possível na resposta, essa [referência](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programar_em_C%2B%2B/Entrada_e_sa%C3%ADda_de_dados#cin.ignore()) pode ser um complemento para o seu entendimento.